# Updating orphaned records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `Type has_many Dresses`. In the `Dress` table, I have a column called `type_id` which references the `Type` model. What I want to do is whenever a `Type` object is deleted, all of the associated `Dress` objects will update their `type_id` to `nil`.

So far, I tried this in the console and it works:

```
> Dress.where(type_id: 3).update_all(type_id: nil)
```

However, when I translate it in the `TypesController` like this:

```
def destroy
  type_id = params[:id]
  if Type.find(type_id).destroy
    Dress.where(:type_id => type_id).update_all(:type_id => nil)
    redirect_to admins_path
  end
end
```

...and try it in the browser, the `Type` object is deleted but the `Dress` `type_id` was not updated.

This is the log output:

```
DELETE FROM "types" WHERE "types"."id" = $1  [["id", 3]]
UPDATE "types" SET position = (position - 1) WHERE (1 = 1 AND position > 2)
COMMIT
UPDATE "dresses" SET "type_id" = NULL WHERE "dresses"."id"
  IN (SELECT "dresses"."id" FROM "dresses" WHERE "dresses"."type_id" = 0)
```

I don't understand why it sets the `type_id = 0` in the last `UPDATE` command but before that it was set correctly in the `DELETE` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dresses, :dependent => :nullify
    ...
end
```

Does not it work?

Comment: Yes, this works. I didn't notice the nullify option the first time I'm browsing through the Rails Guides.